# Swapping function in drag and drop is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

i am creating a to-do app tha uses drag and drop to reorder the elements in the list, the problem is that the function for swaping the elements works fine in the first 5 elements of the list, in the 6th element I get these errors when dragging the element itself and when dragging others to this element  :

> listItems[fromIndex] is undefined

> listItems[toIndex] is undefined

I am not sure what is wrong and why it only happens in the last element as everything is created in the same way

Here it is the HTML:

```
 <body>
  <main>

    <div class="header">
      <h1 class="title">TODO</h1>
      <div onclick="changeTheme()" class="tgl-btn"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="type-todo">
      <div class="circle"></div>
      <input type="text" value="" id="todo-input">
    </div>
    <div class="container-todo">
      <ul class="draggable-list" id="draggable-list">



      </ul>
      
      <div class="footer-div" id="footer-div"></div>
    </div>


    
    <p class="note">Drag and drop to reorder list</p>
  </main>




  

  <script src="./index.js"></script>
</body>
```

And here the JS code:

```
const draggableElement = document.getElementById('draggable-list');


const TodoList = [
    'Complete online Javascript course',
    'Jog around the park 3x',
    '10 minutes meditation',
    'Read for 2hr',
    'Pick up the groceries',
    'Complete todo list',
];

//store items
const listItems =[];



let dragStartIndex;

createList();

//insert items into dom
function createList(){
    [...TodoList]//copies array
    .forEach((todo,index)=>{
        const listItem = document.createElement('li');
        

        // listItem.setAttribute('id','draggable');
        listItem.setAttribute('data-index',index+1);
        listItem.setAttribute('className','draggable');
        listItem.innerHTML=`
        
       
        <label for="showRatings${index + 1}" class="circle${index + 1} check">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox input" name="showRatings${index + 1}" id="showRatings${index + 1}">
        </label>
        <span class="number">${index + 1+"-"}</span>
        <div class="draggable" draggable="true">
        <p class="todo-name" >${todo}</p>
        </div>`;

        

        listItems.push(listItem);

        draggableElement.appendChild(listItem);

       
    });


   
    
}
addEventListeners();

function dragStart() {
    dragStartIndex = +this.closest('li').getAttribute('data-index');
    // console.log('index',dragStartIndex)
}

function dragEnter() {
    this.classList.add('over');
}

function dragLeave() {
    this.classList.remove('over');
}

function dragOver(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // console.log('over')
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function dragDrop() {
    const dragEndIndex= +this.getAttribute('data-index');
    
   
    swapItems(dragStartIndex, dragEndIndex);

    this.classList.remove('over');
}


function swapItems(fromIndex, toIndex) {
    const itemOne = listItems[fromIndex].querySelector('.draggable');
    const itemTwo = listItems[toIndex].querySelector('.draggable');

    // console.log(itemOne,itemTwo);
    // console.log(listItems[fromIndex])
    listItems[fromIndex].appendChild(itemTwo);
    listItems[toIndex].appendChild(itemOne); 
}

function addEventListeners() {
    const draggables = document.querySelectorAll('.draggable');
    const dragListItems = document.querySelectorAll('.draggable-list li');

    draggables.forEach(draggable =>{
        draggable.addEventListener('dragstart',dragStart);
    });

    dragListItems.forEach(item =>{
        item.addEventListener('dragover',dragOver);
        item.addEventListener('drop',dragDrop);
        item.addEventListener('dragenter',dragEnter);
        
        item.addEventListener('dragleave',dragLeave);
    });
    
}
```

Hope you can help me and thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just change dragDrop function . All is ok, I think.

```
function dragDrop() {
    const dragEndIndex= +this.getAttribute('data-index');
    
   
    swapItems(dragStartIndex-1, dragEndIndex-1);

    this.classList.remove('over');
}
```

just change this line.

```
swapItems(dragStartIndex-1, dragEndIndex-1);
```

your index overflow.

Comment: That worked but now that I add a 'div' dynamically with the same class it says this:  **listItems[fromIndex].querySelector is not a function**. Do you have any idea what could it be?

Comment: I check your code step by step then I found it. Now I don't know, how to change you yours code. So I can't tell  about this error.